# NSFetchedResultsController, Specifying number of returned entities?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Is there a way when creating an `NSFetchRequest` to specify how many entities you want returned. In the example below I only want the top 3 Zombie productions that have the most shots, I thought `fetchBatchSize` might do this but it returns batches of 3 until all your Zombie productions have been retrieved. Does anyone know how you might do this?

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController {

    // CREATE FETCH REQUEST
    NSFetchRequest *fRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Production"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains %@", @"Zombie"];
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"shots" ascending:NO];
    [fRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
    [fRequest setFetchBatchSize:3];

    // FETCH RESULTS CONTROLLER
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[self managedDocument] managedObjectContext];
    [self setFetchedResultsController:[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fRequest
                                                                          managedObjectContext:moc
                                                                            sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                cacheName:nil]];
    [[self fetchedResultsController] setDelegate:nil]; // NO UPDATES
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`setFetchLimit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/setFetchLimit%3a) property of `NSFetchRequest`.

**Excerpt from Apple Docs:** *The fetch limit specifies the maximum number of objects that a request should return when executed.*